# trying to write a .bat file to auto login and exit

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

im tyring to write a bat file to ensure i am logged into a remote pc by a certain time so that some other auto processes can run on that pc.

heres where i am

```
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/server /user:**** /pass:*****
mstsc /v:server

ping 8.8.8.8 -n 10

taskkill /im mstsc.exe /f
```

problem im facing is that after lauching the remote pc is doesnt move to the ping until i manually close the cmd window

seems really simple, im just blanking. and if i could schedule it and save my creds in task scheduler i would, current gp doesnt allow me to.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call mstsc with `start` to run mstsc independently of the batch script.

```
start "" mstsc /v:server
```